# Rest API Post with parameters to get search result

Tags: rest, api, xamarin.forms, postman, restsharp

I am in Xamarin Forms and making rest calls to an API, I am new to this. I am wanting to send my search parameters which is:

```
{ "busObIds": [
"8102508"], "searchText": "John"}
```

(this the raw JSON format) to the API endpoint:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost/NameAPI/api/V1/getquicksearchresults");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearer);
```

I also have an Authorization Bearer i need to apply. I am stumbling through this and not sure how to do this correctly, as I was shown how to do in Postman but currently can not convert that into my project in Visual Studio Xamarin Forms. Help please if you can.

1. So am I doing this correct?
2. Do i need to serialize my JSON in model class?
3. Am i posting or getting? as it says POST but im not confident I am doing right.
4. Do i post my parameters in the AddHeader?

Anyway thank you in advance.

***Update:***

```
var _client = new RestClient("http://localhost/NameAPI/api/V1/getquicksearchresults");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearer);
            request.AddParameter("busObIds", "8102508");
            request.AddParameter("searchText", "John");
            IRestResponse response = _client.Execute(request);
            var jsonData = response.Content;
            var jsonObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CiResponse>(jsonData);
            this.CiList = new ObservableCollection<CiItem>();
            if (null != jsonObj && jsonObj.Types != null && jsonObj.Types.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in jsonObj.Types)
                    this.CIList.Add(new CiItem
                    {
                        PublicId = item.PublicId,
                        SubTitle = item.SubTitle,
                        Text = item.Text,
                        Title = item.Title
                    });
            }
```

When running i have no indication that its incorrect, but no output showing on screen.

Comment: According to the code you shared you are using Restsharp, so I would recommend to start with checking the documentation: https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki

Comment: A simple tutorial of Postman application, and getting a success result from that let me get a code snippet to apply in my project. Success! Postman is a great tool for development and rest call testing.